# Writing Arabic in Pycharm console

Tags: python, encoding, console, pycharm, display

In PyCharm I have no problem in printing Arabic in the console, but the problem that I can’t write in Arabic. Instead it is written as weird symbols. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you're using some weird encoding, try to change your file encoding to UTF-8 or UTF-16:

```
Settings → File Encoding → Project Encoding → IDE Encoding
```

more info: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

If that doesn't work it's also possible that your current font doesn't support those characters. Try to use some other font. The editor font can be changed from the preferences:

```
Settings → Editor → Font
```